# How to dynamically specify Spring Restful WebService URL?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest, spring-mvc

I want to dynamically enter my spring restful url, how to do this?
first of all, before i trying to create dynamical url, i create the static one. Here is what i do :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/insert/{id}/{name}/{address}", method = RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=application/json")
public void insertsoheaderdinamis(@PathVariable String id, @PathVariable String name, @PathVariable String address) throws ParseException {


}
```

above is my static url code. in the future, what i need is, i need a new pathvariable like this `localhost:8080/SpringServiceJsonSample/service/updatepool/insert/{here goes id}/{here goes name}/{here goes address}/{new variable goes phone number}/{here goes age}`.

i don't want to change my code, so i decided to create a dynamic url. While i read around internet.

i trying to do this :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/insert/{path}/**", method = RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=application/json")
public void insertdynamicurl(@PathVariable("path") String path, HttpServletRequest request) throws ParseException {

}
```

but this won't do, even i can't get into my function while debuging it. It always give me "noHandlerFound" in my console log. How to do the dynamically url for springrestful service properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at [URI Template Patterns with Regular Expressions](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates-regex) which suggests on using regular expressions in `@RequestMapping` annotations.

The `@RequestMapping` annotation supports the use of regular expressions in URI template variables. The syntax is `{varName:regex}` where the first part defines the variable name and the second - the regular expression. For example:

```
@RequestMapping("/spring-web/{symbolicName:[a-z-]+}-{version:\d\.\d\.\d}.{extension:\.[a-z]}")
  public void handle(@PathVariable String version, @PathVariable String extension) {    
    // ...
  }
}
```

In addition to this, you can match rest of the URL string using request attribute name `HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE`, as shown below.

```
@RequestMapping("/{id}/**")
public void foo(@PathVariable("id") int id, HttpServletRequest request) {
    String restOfTheUrl = (String) request.getAttribute(
        HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shishir's approach is good, but even the regular expression will match the value only up to a first forward slash, because the default `AntPathMatcher` uses a forward slash as a delimiter for path variables.

This means that you'll always have to statically list the mappings with all the possible path variable combinations. However, on the side of function arguments you don't have to list all the path variables, as you can use a map that will catch all the path variables regardless of the count, and this you can use to achieve a level of generality, something like

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/insert/{id}/{name}/{address}", "/insert/{id}/{name}/{address}/{phoneNumber}", "/insert/{id}/{name}/{address}/{phoneNumber}/{age}"} , method = RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=application/json")
public void insertsoheaderdinamis(
        @PathVariable Map<String, String> pathVariables) {
    // to access the values of your path variables do something like
    if (pathVariables.containsKey("id")) {
        String id= pathVariables.get("id");
    }
    // do your stuff
}
```